# Event viewer showing warning on server

Tags: c#, .net, iis, reporting-services, event-viewer

I am getting this warning message on server's Event Viewer log. It is regularly generated with 4-10 minute interval.

Can anyone help?

Event code: 3005

Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred.

Event time: 10/20/2013 9:04:29 PM

Event time (UTC): 10/21/2013 1:04:29 AM

Event ID: 0e9fd5b5a1134c1d928e41260fc89668

Event sequence: 1013 
Event occurrence: 1

Event detail code: 0

Application information:

```
Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT-1-130267026425662500 

Trust level: Full 
Application Virtual Path: / 
Application Path: C:\inetpub\sites\abc.org\ 
Machine name: abc012
```

Process information:

```
Process ID: 6820 

Process name: w3wp.exe 

Account name: IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0
```

Exception information:

```
Exception type: HttpHandlerInputException 

Exception message: Missing URL parameter: IterationId
```

at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HandlerOperation.GetAndEnsureParam(NameValueCollection urlQuery, String paramName)

at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportImageOperation.PerformOperation(NameValueCollection urlQuery, HttpResponse response)

at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at 
System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()

at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Request information:

```
Request URL: http://abcxyz.org/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?ReportSession=4vuhzy45ymyo51rbq3eryf55&Culture=1033&CultureOverrides=True&UICulture=1033&UICultureOverrides=True&ReportStack=1&ControlID=af6bbb1514ef477898efe1da79beebc6&OpType=ReportImage&ResourceStreamID=Blank.gif 

Request path: /Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd 

User host address:  

User: abc123
Is authenticated: True 

Authentication Type: Forms 

Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0
```

Thread information:

```
Thread ID: 15 
Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0 

Is impersonating: False 

Stack trace:
```

at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HandlerOperation.GetAndEnsureParam(NameValueCollection urlQuery, String paramName)

at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportImageOperation.PerformOperation(NameValueCollection urlQuery, HttpResponse response)

at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

at 
System.Web.HttpAplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()

at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: In my case it is happening when user try to access with Internet Explorer 11.